# Is there a way to force sshd to call fsync() at the end of an scp upload?

Tags: scp, ssh, unexpected-shutdown

I've got a Debian Linux-based server that accepts file uploads via scp, and this server tends to get powered off suddenly from time to time.  If the power loss occurs shortly after an scp upload has completed, this can result in the uploaded file(s) showing up truncated (or missing) the next time power is restored.

Is there a way to force sshd (or whatever process is writing the uploaded data to disk... I think it is sshd) to call fsync() when the upload is complete, in order to minimize the chance of data loss due to a power outage?

As an example of the kind of thing I'm looking for, this server also accepts file uploads via Samba/CIFS, and I found that adding the following lines to the [globals] section of my smb.conf helps guard against data loss there:

```
strict sync = yes
sync always = yes
```

So I'm looking for something analogous, perhaps something that I could put into /etc/sshd_config ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way I know of to make sshd do this, though Kyle's solution is certainly a valid one (assuming you're using keys and an agent, and can stand a few seconds between the upload finishing & the `sync` request).

If you're paranoid about data loss I suggest investing in a UPS and a RAID card with a battery backup.
If cost is an issue you can mount the target filesystem with the `sync` option (forces all writes to occur synchronously).

Mounting with `sync` set will be a a performance hit, but when your transfer is done you know the data is all on disk (subject to the whims of disk controller caches, which if you're using a decent RAID controller may be a noticeable delay - see above :).

Answer (score 1):

One of the GNU core-utils is the `sync` command.  So you can just have your upload script ssh in and run that command at the end.  There might be something cleaner than that though.

Comment: well done on the new job dude, don't hesitate to call on me for help or whatever ok - I'm strongest on server hardware, ESX/i and FC/FCoE SAN ok.